# Python efficiency - nested loop structure with matrices

Tags: python, numpy, nested-loops, processing-efficiency

I am new to python, but have been coding in MATLAB for years. I've been working to code a specific problem, which requires nested for loops for multiple matrices to solve a series of equations. I knew how I would code this in MATLAB and then used chatGPT to help convert into python syntax. I am using Spyder interface and python 3.9. Below shows the related code described here, and I would like to understand specific ways to make this run more efficiently. I've read previous answers for similar questions using itertools, but when applied, they don't seem to work.

```
import numpy as np

R1init=[]
R2init=[]
L1init=[]
L2init=[]
p1init=[]
p2init=[]
m1init=[]
m2init=[]
dVrinit=[]
dVlinit=[]

R1 = np.arange(50, 200.001, 2)
R2 = R1  # Since R1 and R2 are identical
L1 = -1*R1
L2 = np.arange(-50,-300.001,-10)

#converted values to be thousands, assuming this would help with matrix sizes.
dVl = 194329/1000  
dVr = 51936/1000  
dVg = 188384/1000  
DR = 0. 
DB = 0.

m1 = np.abs(dVl / R1) 
m2 = np.abs(dVr / L2)


j1 = 0
j2 = 0

for i in R1:
    for j in R2:
        for k in L1:
            for m in L2:
                for n in m1:
                    for q in m2:
                        p1 = ((j2*(1+q)-q)*m+j+dVr)/i
                        p2 = 1-j2*(1+q)+q-(i/m)*(1-j1*(1+n)+n-p1)+dVg/m
                        dVrchk = (q-(j2*q)-q)*m+(p1*i)-j+DR+DB
                        dVlchk =(j1-n+(j1*n))*i+k-(p2*m)
                        dVgchk = (1-j1-p1+n-j1*n)*i-(1-j2-p2+q-j2*q)*m
                        if 0<p2<1.05 and 0<p1<1.05 and dVl-100<dVlchk<dVl+100 and dVr-  100<dVrchk<dVr+100:
                            R1init.append(i)
                            R2init.append(j)
                            L1init.append(k)
                            L2init.append(m)
                            p1init.append(p1)
                            p2init.append(p2)
                            m1init.append(n)
                            m2init.append(q)
                            dVrinit.append(dVrchk)
                            dVlinit.append(dVlchk)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Translating code from one language to another is often more complex than a syntactic trivial transformation (including natural languages). Python codes are interpreted so loops are very inefficient so the the generated code is not good. There are thousands of question on StackOverflow on this topic. While you can use Numpy or JIT to speed up this code, I strongly encourage you to use a native language (e.g. C, C++, Fortran, Rust) to make this fast. The default implementation, CPython, is clearly not suited for this. AFAIK, Matlab use a JIT by default.

Comment: Within the code, this loops over both the array R1, and the array m1, which is derived from R1. I assume that m1 is intended to be derived from the R1 value you are searching, but this searches all possible m1 values, even for R1 values other than the one currently being searched. Are you sure this is what you intended?

Comment: @NickODell, yes. This is the intention. Essentially the result is a "family of solutions" that you then can narrow down with specific knowledge of the given area. It's an engineering application, and since Python is open source, I'm trying to utilize this instead of needing to deal with MATLAB since the licensing is expensive and limiting.

Comment: when I started using MATLAB, v3.5 (and into the early 2000s), it didn't have any jit.  If you wanted any speed you had to use whole-matrix methods, the equivalent of `numpy` 'vectorization'.  If I had to iterate I chose the smallest dimension.  A few iterations on a complex task often is the fastest solution. Do the high-iteration tasks in compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Numba to speed this up, and altering the order that you check the conditions in. That is sufficient to solve this in under a second.

For example, your condition on `p1` does not involve the variables `n` or `k`, so you don't need to loop over all combinations of these to check them.

Similarly, `p2` doesn't depend on `k`, so it can be done outside the `k` loop.

This does have the disadvantage that it changes the order of the solutions, but I'm guessing you don't strongly care what order they're returned in.

These optimizations allow this to be done in under a second.

```
import numba as nb
from numba.typed import List


@nb.njit()
def search_inner(R1, R2, L1, L2, m1, m2):
    dVl = 194329/1000
    dVr = 51936/1000
    dVg = 188384/1000
    DR = 0. 
    DB = 0.

    R1init = List()
    R2init = List()
    L1init = List()
    L2init = List()
    p1init = List()
    p2init = List()
    m1init = List()
    m2init = List()
    dVrinit = List()
    dVlinit = List()
    j1 = 0
    j2 = 0

    for i in R1:
        for j in R2:
            for q in m2:
                for m in L2:
                    # i j q m
                    p1 = ((j2*(1+q)-q)*m+j+dVr)/i
                    if not (0 < p1 < 1.05):
                        continue
                    for n in m1:
                        # q i m n p1
                        p2 = 1-j2*(1+q)+q-(i/m)*(1-j1*(1+n)+n-p1)+dVg/m
                        if not (0 < p2 < 1.05):
                            continue
                        for k in L1:
                            # i j q m p1
                            dVrchk = (q-(j2*q)-q)*m+(p1*i)-j+DR+DB
                            if not (dVr - 100 < dVrchk < dVr + 100):
                                continue
                            # n i k m p2
                            dVlchk =(j1-n+(j1*n))*i+k-(p2*m)
                            if not (dVl - 100 < dVlchk < dVl + 100):
                                continue
                            dVgchk = (1-j1-p1+n-j1*n)*i-(1-j2-p2+q-j2*q)*m
                            # dVgchk is ignored here - Bug?
                            R1init.append(i)
                            R2init.append(j)
                            L1init.append(k)
                            L2init.append(m)
                            p1init.append(p1)
                            p2init.append(p2)
                            m1init.append(n)
                            m2init.append(q)
                            dVrinit.append(dVrchk)
                            dVlinit.append(dVlchk)

    ret = {
        'R1init': R1init,
        'R2init': R2init,
        'L1init': L1init,
        'L2init': L2init,
        'p1init': p1init,
        'p2init': p2init,
        'm1init': m1init,
        'm2init': m2init,
        'dVrinit': dVrinit,
        'dVlinit': dVlinit,
    }
    return ret
def search():
    #converted values to be thousands, assuming this would help with matrix sizes.
    dVl = 194329/1000
    dVr = 51936/1000

    R1 = np.arange(50, 200.001, 2)
    R2 = R1  # Since R1 and R2 are identical
    L1 = -1*R1
    L2 = np.arange(-50,-300.001,-10)

    m1 = np.abs(dVl / R1)
    m2 = np.abs(dVr / L2)

    ret = search_inner(R1, R2, L1, L2, m1, m2)
    # Unwrap typed lists into arrays
    ret = {k: np.array(v, dtype='float64') for k, v in ret.items()}
    return ret
```